# Well defined function meaning

Tags: functions

A function is said to be well defined if x=y implies f(x)=f(y). If x=y then surely wont f(x)=f(y). I cant get this through my head. Plz explain what a well defined function is n what is an ill defined one. It puzzles me a lot to think of an ill defined one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined#Simple_example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One example of a not-well-defined function would be $f(\frac{a}{b})=a+b.$
Then, while $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$, we have $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 3$ but $f(\frac{2}{4})=6.$  So you'll often see, in proofs about rational numbers, that the fractions is specified to be "in lowest terms" and maybe "with denominator positive", so that the operations given are well-defined.

Comment: It would be correct to say that there exists no function that is not well defined. $f$ defined here is not even a function as 1/2 is being mapped to two different values by $f$.

Comment: @Koro I also never got the notion of a "well-defined" function. If the relation $f$ does not satisfy the "function" definition then it is simply not a function but is just a relation.

Comment: @Aelx  It might not even be a relation or it might be a function but you can't work out it's values.  Let $f(x)$ be "the number of words in the sentence that best describes $x$."

Answer (score 4):

A function $f$ is well defined or 'single-valued' in the sense that $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,b')\in f$ imply that $b=b'$. This operation is written as $f(a)=b$.

What this means is, that a single element of $A$ cannot have more than one image in $B$ under $f:A\to B$. Thus the mapping $f$ is a particular relation $f\subset A\times B$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I say: $f(x) = $ some number greater than $x$

Then of course you say 'well, that could be lots of things, e.g. f(5) could be 6, or 7, or ...  So, what *is* it?!'

OK, so the problem is that this 'function' does not uniquely specify what f(x) is for any x, i.e. You could have x= 5 , y= 5, but f(x) = 6, and f(y) = 7. So, it is not well-defined, since in this case x=y does apparently not imply f(x) =f(y).

Indeed, most mathematicians therefore don't consider this a function at all! That is, typically we say that a function *must* have the feature that function values are uniquely defined or else it is just not a function. You probably think about it that way as well, which is why you see functions as *automatically* well-defined, wondering what the requirement that functions are well-defined is all about: aren't they by definition of being a function well-defined?!

Well, you have to realize that the function at some point does need to be defined ... And if our definition is a complicated one, it may not be immediately clear whether it is well-defined our not. So, we always have to make sure that what we *intend* to be be our 'function' is *in fact* well-defined. This is what we are really after when we say that functions need to be well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

What makes the concept of a well-defined function $f$ confusing is the fact that functions are by definition well-defined.  So to explain what it means to not be well-defined, we have to take an example where $f$ is not a function.

Lets take the following procedure and call it $f$:  The input is an integer $n$. The output of $f$ is an element of $\{n+1,\ldots,n+6\}$ determined by rolling a dice. This procedure takes an integer $n$ as input, and returns an integer as output. But it is not well-defined, because if you compute $f(n)$ several times for the same $n$, you do not always get the same output. The term used to describe this behavior is to say that $f$ is not well-defined.

Suppose you have some procedure $f$ that takes as input an element of a set $X$, and returns as output an element of a set $Y$. Then you may only call $f$ a function if you can prove that $x=y$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$. This might seem obvious at first, but it is often non-trivial. For example, suppose that the procedure $f$ involves choosing an element of some non-empty set.  In this case, to prove that $f$ is well-defined (and thus: a function), you have to prove that any choice you could have made will result in the same output $f(x)$.